# Short code not working out of themes folder

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to display shortcode in file `Wordpress/order.php`, but it is not working.I am using this php code to display `echo do_shortcode('[wp-like-locker]');`

But it displays this error message.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function do_shortcode() in D:\new\htdocs\business\upload.php on line 144
```

I am using this code out of template folder.

How can I display this code out of tempalate folder?

Comment: Are you using this code outside of a wordpress template?

Comment: Of course is not working! do_shordcode is a core wordpress function. You can't use it on a file that is now part of wordpress... creating a file in worpdress directory that doesn't make it a part of wordpress.

Comment: why out of themes folder ?/

Comment: It is a my custom page. and I need to display shortcode at this page.

Answer (score 1):

To access WP functions you need to include `wp-load.php`:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( '../path/to/wp-load.php' );
```